# How to list azure vm images by API using Python script?

Tags: python, azure, image, api, virtual-machine

Whether it is possible to list above questions by api using Python script

I am not getting exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

See the API here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/list-all?tabs=HTTP
`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01`

Use `PostMan` or similar application to do this.

You need a header `Authorization Bearer access-token`.
`headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['accessToken'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Also see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-overview
- https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python
- https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
- https://jwt.ms/
- https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/azure-resource-manager-api-calls-from-python/